# Use of getActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-dialogfragment

First of all sorry if this post may seem a duplicate but I am very new to Android programming and posting this question only when I am still not able to get a satisfactory answer for use of getActivity.

Theoretically I understand the use of getActivity() from the several posts here but I am confused how it is working in my code.

I have a class MainActivity from which I am creating a dialog onclick of a checkbox.
I have another class TaxDialog where the dialog is implemented. On click of Yes/No buttons I am calling methods define in MainActivity class.
 Below are the codes:

**MainActivty**

```
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener {

// onCheck of checkbox showNoticeDialog is called

    public void showNoticeDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        Log.i("MyActivity", "Inside showNoticeDialog");
        DialogFragment dialog = new TaxDialog();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("title", "Test");
        args.putString("message", "Test Message");
        dialog.setArguments(args);

        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "dialog");


    }
   public void doPositiveClick(){
       Log.i("MyActivity", "Inside +ve");
   }
    public void doNegativeClick(){
        Log.i("MyActivity", "Inside -ve");
    }

}
```

**TaxDialog**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;

public class TaxDialog extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Bundle args = getArguments();

        String title = args.getString("title");

        String message = args.getString("message");
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle(title);

        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(getTargetRequestCode(), Activity.RESULT_OK, null);
                Log.i("MyActivity", "Expected fault area.");
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).doNegativeClick();
            }
        });
        builder.create();

        return builder.create();
    }

}
```

Here I want to understand how below line works

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).doPositiveClick();
```

and also please make me aware of other ways of doing the same thing (something like MainActivity.this.getActivity() or something else).

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

Thanks everyone. Probably I framed the question incorrectly. My only doubt was how getActivity() returns the Activity reference. Now I understand.

Comment: When you use fragments it is only way to get context. As above, you are using `DialogFragment` and in `OnClickListener` there is need of context.

Comment: The best advice and I'm sorry to be rude would be, get a good Java book and read it before jumping into Android, anyway just to Answer your question, that line of code is getting a reference of the activity by calling getActivity, cast it to MainActivity and call the doPositive method of it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets split it up:

- `getActivity()` can be used in a Fragment for getting the parent `Activity` of the `Fragment` (basically the Activity that displayed the Fragment).
- `((MainActivity) getActivity())` additionally casts the result of `getActivity()` to MainActivity. Usually, you just know that `getActivity()` returns an object of type `Activity`, but using this *cast*, you tell the compiler that you are sure the object is a specific subclass of `Activity`, namely `MainActivity`. You need to do that in your case, because `doPositiveClick()` is only implemented in `MainActivity`, and not in `Activity`, so you have to assure the compiler the object is a `MainActivity`, and it will respond to the method `doPositiveClick()`.
- `doPositiveClick()` simply calls that method on the `MainActivity` object that is returned by `getActivity()`.

Comment: Thanks. I understand this. I think I framed my question incorrectly. :(.
I'll put it this very simple way .. it's because TaxDialog is instantiated from MainActivity it gets associated with MainActivity?

Comment: Well, it rather is because it is started (shown) from MainActivity, to be 100% correct. Simply put, it's the Activity that was shown before the DialogFragment was shown.

Comment: Thanks. This was the only doubt. :)

Comment: Hello there.I am trying to use String msg = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).msg; and I get error on getActivity.It says: Cannot resolve mehtod getActivity().

Any chance you could help?

Comment: @Vlad: `getActivity()` only works in classes that implement this method, e.g. `Fragment`. In what class are you trying to call it?

Comment: I am calling it in onCreate of a second activity class.And I am trying to get a String variable from the first activity class (without using intent).

Comment: Never directly access an Activity's member fields or methods from another Activity. I recommend reconsidering your design.

Comment: Casting getActivity to MainActivity (or whatever your parent class is) worked for me o/

Answer (score 3):

The approach you are using is not the best way to accomplish what you want to do. Android have a good support for listeners, and for communicating with fragments. So, lets see how to communicate fragment->activity direction.

First, you need to make your MainActivity a listener from what happens on a dialog, so the best way to do this is implementing **DialogInterface.OnClickListener** on your **MainActivity** and override the **onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)** method, this method will be called from your fragmen. So until now everything is done in your MainActivity.

Now, in your fragment, you have to override the **onAttach(Activity activity)** method, this is the first method called when the fragment is built and this method comes with our **parent Activity**, inside this method initialize the listener of your fragment (your MainActivity).

Your fragment should look like this:

```
private DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Bundle args = getArguments();

    String title = args.getString("title");

    String message = args.getString("message");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(title);

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //Calling our MainActivity Listener with a positive answer
            listener.onClick(getDialog(), 1);
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            //Calling our MainActivity Listener with a negative answer
            listener.onClick(getDialog(), 0);
        }
    });
    builder.create();

    return builder.create();
}

@Override
  public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    if (activity instanceof DialogInterface.OnClickListener) {
      listener = (DialogInterface.OnClickListener) activity;
    } else {
      throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
          + " must implemenet DialogInterface.OnClickListener");
    }
  }
```

And your main activity onClick() method should look like this:

```
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    switch (which) {
    case 0:
        //Do your negative thing
        break;

    case 1:
        //Do your positive thing
        break;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked "+ which, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

This is the best approach to do what you want to do, forget about "hard" cast your MainActivity class. Hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can jsut do

```
  this.doPsitiveClick();
```

((MainActivity)getActivity())  is just getting the current active activity and casting that to be MainActivity..

Comment: This in an OnClickListener refers to an OnClickListener instance.

Comment: my bad 
     MainActivity.this.doPositiveClick()

Comment: Thanks. I understand it is typecasting to Main Activity. But wouldn't this refers to the reference of the current class?

Comment: When I do this MainActivity.this.doPositiveClick(), I get error "MainActivity is not an enclosing class."

Comment: MainActivity.this.doPositiveClick() won't work because you are not in the scope of a `MainActivity` instance.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fragments` it is only way to get context. As above, you are using `DialogFragment` and in `OnClickListener` there is need of context.

- getActivity() is user-defined.
- `public final Activity getActivity()` - Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with.

For your code, in `TaxDialog` which is extending `DialogFragment` need a context to create `AlertDialog` with `AlertDialog.Builder`. So here, `getActivity()` as a parameter in `AlertDialog.Builder` is passing as `context` which tells to `AlertDialog` Fragment that by which activity it is attached to.

Comment: `getActivity()` is user-defined?

Comment: It isn't the only way. A reference to the parent activity is passed into onAttach() which is the first method called in a fragment's lifecycle.