# What is meant by "Activity this fragment is currently associated with"?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Here in the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getActivity%28%29) I see that when I call **getActivity()** from my fragment class, I get the activity object that the fragment is currently associated with.

Suppose if fragment is associated with MainActivity then getActivity() doesn't give an object of the MainActivity class.

I'm unable to understand the difference between `Activity activity;` and `Activity activity = getActivity();`
Can anyone please explain me what this "*Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with*" actually mean ?

Sorry for asking simple question.
Thanks.

**Edit :**

Went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712234/use-of-getactivity) also, got a better understanding.

Comment: "Can anyone please explain me what this "Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with" actually mean ?" -- it means the activity whose `FragmentManager` is managing the fragment, if any. For example, if you add a `Fragment` to a `FragmentManager` via a `FragmentTransaction`, that `Fragment` is considered to be associated with the activity whose `FragmentManager` you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest answer would be:

"Return the Activity this fragment is currently associated with"
is activity to which this fragment was added.

Then to make things clear.

```
Activity activity;
```

This creates reference to activity object, and at start this one is empty (equal to null), until you write some activity object to it.

```
Activity activity = getActivity();
```

Here we do 2 things, firstly we create reference to activity object and then we write to this object value of function getActivity(), that if called from fragment will return associated activity.

And lastly why this is not MainActivity? Well it actually may or may not be. :)
And to check if this is actually MainActivity try this :)

```
Activity activity = getActivity(); // let get our activity
if (activity == null) { 
    /* this mean we are not attached to activity, possibly, fragment was not shown yet */ 
} 
if (activity instanceof MainActivity) { // we check if activity is actually Main activity.
    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) activity; // and if it is we can do something with it after we cast it.
}
```

Then at the end i will add one link that might also help: [fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)

Comment: Hi Inverce!, Thanks for explaining. :)  I would like to ask one more, if you don't mind. You said "it actually may or may not be". Can u please tell me what is that it depends on so that it may actually become an instance of MainActivity itself ?

Comment: Fragment is not part of activity nor is activity part of fragment, instead fragment is piece of ui that you can use multiple times in multiple Activities, 

MainActivity happens to be activity auto generated by AndroidStudio/Eclipse when you create a project, its default activity to be displayed at start, You can add other activities to your project, and to each activity you can add your fragment. Then for each instance of added fragment, the activity you get is actualy the activity to which you added that fragment, so ... part 2 comming soon...

Comment: if i create another Activity lets call it SmileyActivity and add to it my fragment, methodGetActivity will return exactly instance of that SmileyActivity, going further if, i add my fragment to MainActivity and SmileyActivity for each added fragment, method getActivity will return proper Activity :)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

Comment: also if i happen to answer your question please do accept my answer :)

Answer (score 3):

Association is simple.

Like in real life.

- You are a student (**Fragment**).
- You are getting knowledge in Chicago university (**MainActivity**).

As you are student you will be associated(attached) to university.

And if someone ask you :

-*What is your university?(**call getActivity() from Fragment**)*

You will answer :

-*I from Chicago university(**return object which refered to MainActivity**)*

If you change the university - you will respond differently.
That's all :)

Comment: actually i did like this answer :)